# Pandas datetime format without strftime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a CSV file that I open using pandas.

The format is DATE | AMOUNT1 | AMOUNT2

I use `df[df.columns[0]]=pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')` to convert the date to my preferd format, however using `dt.strftime` changes the type of the data from datetime to strings.

Now, if I need to find the difference between two dates, for example, from the first datapoint to the last datapoint using `print(df.iloc[-1][0]-df.iloc[0][0])` it will output an error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

My question is: is there a way to have the same date format, without losing the datetime type?

I tried `df[df.columns[0]]=pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]], dayfirst=True, format='%d-%m-%Y')` but it doesn't really work, the format doesn't change to be the disired.

Comment: do you have an example of the entry data format and the desired ouput format ?

Comment: @DanielWeigel The CSV columns are like
29/09/2019 20 85 |
03/10/2019 20 265 |
09/10/2019 20 410 |
15/10/2019 20 577 |
20/10/2019 20 703 |
27/10/2019 20 876 |
31/10/2019 20 42
and I want the date format to be 31-10-2019

Comment: No you can't (or you should modify the repr of the datetime object).

Comment: @mozway what do you mean by modyfing the repr of the datetime?